# How to change color of the square outside the canvas from white to dark/black in Illustrator CS5

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

Trying to figure out how to change the color of this square outside the canvas in Illustrator CS5.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I remember when in the Adobe Illustrator release sequence the UI dark/light toggles were added, but I can say that in current Illustrator CC, we get this option in the UI portion of the user preferences:

[image]

I'd bet if you have the ability to set this parameter in CS5, it will be in a similar location.

Comment: Unfortunately, 'user interface' in CS5 doesn't have these options.

Comment: @Ramona, Yes. The ability change pasteboard color is a more recent change... Maybe CS6, most definitely CC. There isn't a way to change it in your version of Illustrator.

Answer (score 3):

For **CS5** there is **no option** to alter the pasteboard color, You need *CS6 or greater* to alter that color in Illustrator.